# How to set data for logistic regression in scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, logistic-regression

I am new to scala and I want to implement a logistic regression model.So initially I load a csv file as below:

```
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
 val df = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
    .option("header", "true")
    .option("inferSchema", "true")
    .load("D:/sample.txt")
```

The file is as below:

```
P,P,A,A,A,P,NB
N,N,A,A,A,N,NB
A,A,A,A,A,A,NB
P,P,P,P,P,P,NB
N,N,P,P,P,N,NB
A,A,P,P,P,A,NB
P,P,A,P,P,P,NB
P,P,P,A,A,P,NB
P,P,A,P,A,P,NB
P,P,A,A,P,P,NB
P,P,P,P,A,P,NB
P,P,P,A,P,P,NB
N,N,A,P,P,N,NB
N,N,P,A,A,N,NB
N,N,A,P,A,N,NB
N,N,A,P,A,N,NB
N,N,A,A,P,N,NB
N,N,P,P,A,N,NB
N,N,P,A,P,N,NB
A,A,A,P,P,A,NB
A,A,P,A,A,A,NB
A,A,A,P,A,A,NB
A,A,A,A,P,A,NB
A,A,P,P,A,A,NB
A,A,P,A,P,A,NB
P,N,A,A,A,P,NB
N,P,A,A,A,N,NB
P,N,A,A,A,N,NB
P,N,P,P,P,P,NB
N,P,P,P,P,N,NB
```

Then I want to train the model by below code:

```
val lr = new LogisticRegression()
      .setMaxIter(10)
      .setRegParam(0.3)
      .setElasticNetParam(0.8)
      .setFeaturesCol("Feature")
      .setLabelCol("Label")
```

Then I fit the model by below:

```
 val lrModel = lr.fit(df)

println(lrModel.coefficients +"are the coefficients")
println(lrModel.interceptVector+"are the intercerpt vactor")
println(lrModel.summary +"is summary")
```

But it is not printing the results.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

from your code:

```
val lr = new LogisticRegression()
      .setMaxIter(10)
      .setRegParam(0.3)
      .setElasticNetParam(0.8)
      .setFeaturesCol("Feature")  <- here
      .setLabelCol("Label") <- here
```

you are setting `features` column and `label` column. As you didn't mention column names, i am assuming the column containing `NB` values is your label and you want to include all others are the columns for prediction.

All predictor variables that you want include in your model, needs to be in form of single vector column, generally called as `features` column. You need to create it using `VectorAssembler` as follows:

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler
import org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vectors

//creating features column
val assembler = new VectorAssembler()
  .setInputCols(Array(" insert your column names here "))
  .setOutputCol("Feature")
```

Refer: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features.html#vectorassembler.

Now you can proceed to fit the logistic regression model. `pipeline` is used to combine multiple transformations before`fitting` the data.

```
val pipeline = new Pipeline().setStages(Array(assembler,lr))

//fitting the model
val lrModel = pipeline.fit(df)
```

Comment: If I use this the lrModel  cannot produce any coefficients ,summary or any other things.Could you please explain why is it like that

Comment: Spark ML can only take numerical values as input. since you predictor columns contain categorical values (P, N, A, ...), you need to convert them to numerical values first. Use `StringIndexer` or `OneHotEncoder` to do it and pass the resulting column names to `VectorAssembler` input. Refer: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features.html#stringindexer and  https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features.html#onehotencoder. I hope it is clear to you.